# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message appears

Tags: c

when running this program, it prints to the screen "Please enter a character: " and allows me to input a character 4 times. After that nothing happens, and when I hit enter, the message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" comes up and I'm not sure why. If anyone could help that would be great, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
char a[5];
int i;

for (i=0; i<4; i++){
printf("Please enter a character: ");
scanf("%s", &a[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<4; i++){
printf("%s", a[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Format specifier `%s` is to specify a string. Use `%c` for a character.

Comment: almost always compile with -Wall option to double check

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", &a[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &a[i]);
```

`%s` is used to scan a string, if you want to scan character then use `%c` since you are scanning in a loop you need to take care of ignoring the non-whitepsace characters

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

You are using `"%s"` where `"%c"` is required, both in the call to `scanf` and in the call to `printf`.

For `scanf`, use `" %c"` so that non-whitespace characters are skipped.

For `printf`, just use `"%c"`.

Comment: I tried the %c before just not with a space, but I did now and it worked! thank you so much